# Create an uninheriated copy of Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, copy, dataset

i need to copy a datatable (in a dataset) to an independent datatable. my purpose is that to hold an original cindependent copy of datatable to restore it to the dataset whwenever i want.
i used this code:`copiedDataTable = frm.DataSet.Tables["myoriginaldatatable"].Copy();` but it works just like Clone() command and create the structure of originaldatatable but the rows are empty where as originaldatatable rows are not empty as i traced.

in another try i used th below code:

```
copiedDataTable = frmMainForm.DataSet.Tables["originalDataTable"];
```

this command make an good copy of originaldatatable. but when i clear the original datatable from dataset for restoring copieddatatable, the copieddtatable is also cleared and rows gets to be empty.(restoring through this code:)

```
frmMainForm.DataSet.Tables["originalDataTable"].Clear();
                frmMainForm.DataSet.Tables.Remove("originalDataTable");
                frmMainForm.projectDataSet.Tables.Add(copiedDataTable);
```

how can i make an independent copy?

Comment: As per the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) *"Copy creates a new DataTable with the same structure and data as the original DataTable. To copy the structure to a new DataTable, but not the data, use Clone."*

Comment: i need the data also but copy() command does not copy row data to the new table.

Comment: try to call `frmMainForm.DataSet.Tables["originalDataTable"].AcceptChanges()` method first then copy the table. The rows might be not accepted if it has inserted manually by code.

Comment: don't restore the original table directly by initializing it. .net is handling the object by HashCode not by variable name or by its key. So, You should update the rows and cell values one by one in a loop instead of whole datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `Copy()` method will copy the data also.

As per the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) *"Copy creates a new DataTable with the same structure and data as the original DataTable. To copy the structure to a new DataTable, but not the data, use Clone."*

When you inserts the row in the data table manually the newly inserted rows are in New Row State. So, the values cannot be return from this kind of rows. Even when you update any value in the DataTable cell then the status of that cell value is Edited. Without accepting changes you cannot return the updated value from the data table.

for example if you have updated any value like

```
dt.Rows[0]["MyCell"] = "MyValue"; //before that the value was "Old Value"
```

now, if I try to fetch that value from that cell then it will return old value or null if there was not.

```
string myValue = dt.Rows[0]["MyCell"];
```

to end the initialization you have to call the `AcceptChanges()` method of datatable after updating value.

```
dt.Rows[0]["MyCell"] = "MyValue";
dt.AcceptChanges();
```